# Erro ao inserir no BD

Tags: php, pdo

Galera, estou com um problema ao cadastrar cliente no BD. Quando clico no botao cadastrar, ele só atualiza a página e não insere o cliente no BD. Não aparece erro e nada. Só atualiza o formulário e pronto. Quando eu tiro o dados array(da imagem 2) e coloco apenas um echo pra ver se roda, ele aparece que foi inserido, mas quando eu uso esse dados com o array que ta instanciado pra inserir no BD, ele não insere.
O que pode ser? To pegando essas aulas do youtube e meu código esta do mesmo jeito do que vi e o cara não responde.

[image: ERRO 1]
[image: ERRO 2]

Answer (score 1):

O fato do código não mostrar o erro, é porque tu estás retornando **false** quando um erro é lançando no **try..catch**.

> **Dica:** Evite ao máximo fazer isso. Sempre trate os erros e sempre armazene esses erros em um log, assim você saberá como seu código está se comportando.

O erro está na linha `if ($inserir->execute()($pegaValores));`. O correto seria (eu acho, pois não conheço a vídeo aula) `if ($inserir->execute($pegaValores));`. Está com parenteses a mais.

Comment: Cara que inferno... Eu olhei o código todo e não vi essa praga desse parenteses ai... Era esse infeliz mesmo... aff..
Muito obrigado pela resposta...
Salvou meu dia